# How to insert table name into query as variable?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make a query to select a table from database. I created a list of table names and exported it to a list, saved necessary list fields as variables, then inserted these variables into a database query to export data. I do not initially know name of table but find it through logic and write it to a variable. It gives me an error:

```
uch = "_uch"
kam = "_kamera"
pot = "_uzvvod"

conn = sqlite3.connect("kotelnaya.sqlite")
table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", conn)

l = len(table)
m = [0] * l
i = 0
k = 1
for k in range(l):
    m[i] = table.at[i, "name"]
    i = i + 1

for num in m:
    if uch in str(num):
        stroka_uch = num

for num in m:
    if kam in str(num):
        stroka_kam = num

for num in m:
    if pot in str(num):
        stroka_pot = num

table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM {}".format(stroka_uch), conn)
```

Error:

```
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "7": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Z_Python_TGRaschet\venv\database_from_to.py", line 70, in <module>
    table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM {}".format(stroka_uch), conn)
  File "C:\Z_Python_TGRaschet\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 397, in read_sql_query
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "C:\Z_Python_TGRaschet\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2078, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "C:\Z_Python_TGRaschet\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2030, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.errors.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM Datatable 7 Test 2_uch': near "7": syntax error
```

Comment: You can't use parameters in DDL. You will have to construct the query string dynamically beforehand and then pass it to `execute`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can you kindly suggest how this can be done. I try, but still only in the process, the beginning of mastering all the possibilities Python and SQLite. Please.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I do not see any DDL in question.

Comment: You need to show your schema

Answer (score -1):

This would be the easiest solution I guess:
sql = "select * from " + stroka_uch
table = pd.read_sql_query(sql = sql, con = conn)